# Hadoop MapReduce - program wroks on file-system but not with HDFS

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

Hadoop newbie here. So I just configured a single-node-setup and I'm not sure where the files should be placed?! my understanding is that it should be on the HDFS. So I added a text file 'zulu.txt' to my HDFS with eclipse using "upload file to DFS" (right click on the DFS; see image below)

When I use

```
String input = "/user/irobot-pc/irobot/In/";
```

I get the following error code: **Input path does not exist**

```
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.InvalidInputException: Input path does not exist: file:/user/irobot-pc/irobot/In
at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.FileInputFormat.listStatus(FileInputFormat.java:224)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.FileInputFormat.getSplits(FileInputFormat.java:241)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient.writeNewSplits(JobClient.java:885)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient.submitJobInternal(JobClient.java:779)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job.submit(Job.java:432)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job.waitForCompletion(Job.java:447)
at com.testdrive.WordCount.main(WordCount.java:37)
```

but when indicating the input on my **local file system** - it works!

```
String input = "C:\\Users\\iRobot\\Desktop\\Pop";
```

Ha?! this doesn't make sense to me. I was under the impression that the hadoop file system should be read, no?

Question: I'd like to move to a 'Cluster Setup' and I know that the files must be located under the HDFS. How can I fix it locally before moving up?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You need to tell your code that you intend to use HDFS and not the local FS. And you can do that with the help of a **Configuration** object. Add these lines in your job :

```
Configuration conf = new Configuration();
conf.addResource(new Path("$HADOOP_HOME/conf/core-site.xml"));
conf.addResource(new Path("$HADOOP_HOME/conf/hdfs-site.xml"));
```

Otherwise your code will look for the input inside your local FS.

HTH

Comment: when you write $HADOOP_HOME - does it mean that I need to set HADOOP_HOME in the environment variable of the OS (win)? when I specify the exact path 'C:/cygwin64/usr/local/hadoop-0.20.2/conf/core-site.xml' it works.